# What is the equivalent of d3.svg.line().interpolate('monotone') in d3 v4?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

What is the equivalent of `d3.svg.line().interpolate('monotone')` in d3.js v4?

Comment: In your case, you have to choose between `d3.curveMonotoneX` or `d3.curveMonotoneY`.

Comment: Thanks @GerardoFurtado It works fine now